# Show data labels inside donut pie chart p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, donut-chart

I'm building a p5js donut chart, but I'm struggling to show the data labels in the middle. I think I have managed to get the boundaries right for it, but how would match the angle that I'm in? Or is there a way of matching just through the colours?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/enTBo.png

I have started by trying to match the boundaries of the chart to the pointer, which I managed to do using mouseX and mouseY. Any suggestions, please?

```
      if(mouseX >= width / 2 - width * 0.2  && mouseY >= height / 2 - width * 0.2 
        && mouseX <= width / 2 + width * 0.2 && mouseY <= height / 2 + width * 0.2)
        {
          //console.log("YAY!!! I'm inside the pie chart!!!");

        } 
      else 
      { 
        textSize(14);
        text('Hover over to see the labels', width / 2, height / 2); 
      }
    };


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/enTBo.png
```

Comment: I'm using Recharts.js and for this purpose exists next components. Look at the example https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomActiveShapePieChart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could theoretically use the [`get()` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get) to check the color of the pixel under the mouse cursor and correlate that with one of the entries in your dataset, I think you would be much better off doing the math to determine which segment the mouse is currently over. And conveniently p5.js provides helper functions that make it very easy.

In the example you showed you are only checking if the mouse cursor is in a rectangular region. But in reality you want to check if the mouse cursor is within a circle. To do this you can use the [`dist(x1, y1, x2, y2)` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/dist). Once you've established that the mouse cursor is over your pie chart, you'll want to determine which segment it is over. This can be done by finding the angle between a line draw from the center of the chart to the right (or whichever direction is where you started drawing the wedges), and a line drawn from the center of the chart to the mouse cursor. This can be accomplished using the [`angleBetween()` function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/angleBetween) of `p5.Vector`.

Here's a working example:

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
const thickness = 40;

let segments = {
  foo: 34,
  bar: 55,
  baz: 89
};

let radius = 80, centerX, centerY;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(thickness);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(20);

  centerX = width / 2;
  centerY = height / 2;
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  let keys = Object.keys(segments);
  let total = keys.map(k => segments[k]).reduce((v, s) => v + s, 0);
  let start = 0;

  // Check the mouse distance and angle
  let mouseDist = dist(centerX, centerY, mouseX, mouseY);
  // Find the angle between a vector pointing to the right, and the vector
  // pointing from the center of the window to the current mouse position.
  let mouseAngle =
    createVector(1, 0).angleBetween(
      createVector(mouseX - centerX, mouseY - centerY)
    );
  // Counter clockwise angles will be negative 0 to PI, switch them to be from
  // PI to TWO_PI
  if (mouseAngle < 0) {
    mouseAngle += TWO_PI;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    stroke(colors[i]);
    let angle = segments[keys[i]] / total * TWO_PI;
    arc(centerX, centerY, radius, radius, start, start + angle);

    // Check mouse pos
    if (mouseDist > radius - thickness / 2 &&
      mouseDist < radius + thickness / 2) {

      if (mouseAngle > start && mouseAngle < start + angle) {
        // If the mouse is the correct distance from the center to be hovering over
        // our "donut" and the angle to the mouse cursor is in the range for the
        // current slice, display the slice information
        push();
        noStroke();
        fill(colors[i]);
        text(`${keys[i]}: ${segments[keys[i]]}`, centerX, centerY);
        pop();
      }
    }

    start += angle;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Paul! Thank you very much! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm having some issues though with the mouseAngle, it's not getting past PI, when it gets to the half of the pie chart (3.14) it goes backwards to 0, any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Yes, for 2d vectors the angleBetween function will return values between 0 and PI for clockwise angles and between 0 and negative PI for counterclockwise angles.

Comment: Wouldn't that be solved when we use: 
`if (mouseAngle < 0) {
    mouseAngle += TWO_PI;
  }`? When debugging the same thing on your example it goes past PI up to 2PI which then can be matched to the start angle.

Comment: Yes, that code in my example is designed to handle the case where angles are between negative PI. Since my example is working I can be sure about why you are seeing different behavior. You might want to post another question with a minimal reproducible example of just the angle issue.

Comment: Sure! Thank you very much for you help Paul!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the source of the problem was that @thenewbie experienced: it is the p5 library being used. I was using the p5.min.js and experiencing the same problem. Once I started using the full p5.js library, the issue was resolved and @Paul's script worked.
Here is a link I came across while researching this which put me onto the solution:
https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/3973

Thanks Paul for the clear explanations and code above.